# C# MVC3 - New Membership Providers (System.Web.Providers) and old Membership classes (System.Web.Security)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, azure-sql-database

I got my app running very well when I was testing locally, with Membership providers and Database. My nightmare began when I tried to run it in Windows Azure plataform.

Since then, I read a lot of articles about running aspnet_regsql in Sql Azure, and the new universal Membership providers. But I can't realize how to use the new Providers, and I'm getting really confused about System.Web.Providers and System.Web.Security classes and methods. When I tried to create a new user with the new Providers, the creation failed with a Null Exception, even if I had all the parameters placed and the build was ok.

My project is totally ready, I just need to upload it to the host.

How could I make it run in Windows Azure easily? Or should I learn how to use the new universal Providers and adjust all my project to that?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that System.Web.Providers is required to run your application on Azure, at least without any heavy code lifting. Scott Hanselman outlines the basics of installing and using System.Web.Providers in his recent blog post: [Introducing System.Web.Providers - ASP.NET Universal Providers for Session, Membership, Roles and User Profile on SQL Compact and SQL Azure](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx).

Another resource that may be helpful is Wade Wegner's post [Deploying the Windows Azure ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Role](http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/08/deploying-the-windows-azure-asp-net-mvc-3-web-role/).

In short, after installing System.Web.Providers in your project using NuGet, it will reconfigure your web.config to include two connections strings, one for ApplicationServices, and another for the DefaultConnection. You will need to updated these with your Azure connection string, but make sure you append "MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" to both connection strings.